# Output a string from a function that was used as a range within the function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to print the results from this custom vLookup to include the pWorkRng as a string. I am using VBA in excel.

If pWorkRng=B1:B5, the first xResult = Dog, the second xResult = Cat, I would like the function to output:

(B1:B5=Dog)+(B1:B5=Cat)

Right now it Prints: Dog Cat

Current Code:

```
Function MYVLOOKUP(pValue As String, pWorkRng As Range, pIndex As Long)
Dim lineItemRange As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim xResult As String
xResult = ""
For Each rng In pWorkRng
    If rng = pValue Then
        xResult = xResult & rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
    End If
Next
MYVLOOKUP = xResult
End Function
```

[image: Sample of myvlookup formula as is]

Comment: `pRngString = pWorkRng.Value` seems problematic. Most likely the right-hand side is 2D Variant array, if `pWorkRng` is a multi-cell range.

Comment: @BigBen Sorry that is something that should be removed, and was leftover from an attempt to solve this problem

Comment: So the output should be literally `(A1:A6=Dog)+(A1:A6=Cat)`? You should work with `pWorkRng.Address(False,False)` then.

Comment: @BigBen it would change everytime with a different range used in the function. Also where would it go in my code so that it prints properly. "Dog", "Cat", and "A1:A6" are initially arguments in the function

Comment: You may want to add a screenshot. I'm confused as to what arguments you're passing, and what the expected result actually is given your data.

Comment: If you're passing a `String`, then please change the argument to `pWorkRng As String` too.

Comment: @BigBen, hi Ben, I've attached a sample of how the function works right now.

Comment: @BigBen Rather than Displaying DogCat, I would like it to display (B1:B5=Dog)+(B1:B5=Cat). Should I create a new variable in the function that is a string in which I type the range I would like displayed?

Comment: You should probably amend your question as it refers to A1:A6.

Comment: `xResult = xResult & "(" & pWorkRng.Address(0,0) & "=" &  rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1) & ")"`

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you very much, works like a charm

Comment: May I ask, what are you going to do with the output?

Comment: It ultimately went into this function @ScottCraner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65007424/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-arrays-from-other-sheets-of-varying-sizes-with-a-simp

Comment: You can probably skip all the vba with a correctly constructed sumproduct.