# Is there a way to evaluate arrays from other sheets of varying sizes with a simple function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that creates a custom function & array based on changing circumstances in data on one sheet. If I try to evaluate it on my main sheet, it returns #value, but if I evaluate it on the sheet the array comes from it returns the correct output. Any idea how to get around this if the 3-d array size is changing?

The array is returned because I am working with a complicated sumproduct function. The sumproduct function is the only function nested within the evaluate formula.

My Evaluate VBA currently looks like:

```
Function Makeformula(Ref As String)
Application.Volatile
Makeformula = Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

Hi Ben,

Summary: (1a) and (2a) below will pull the right result in Sheet 1 if I copy and paste the output of (1) and (2) into new cells and run the text as a function (by adding the equal sign). (1) works with either solution presented and (2) doesn't as is. (2) is an array as the sumproduct pulls two values for the sumproduct.

I tried both answers you gave to no avail. I'll attach some code below to show you and bold the Long formula to make things easier on the eyes.

Similarly to before, your answers work when my sumproduct ultimately ends up generating the text value seen in (1), but not (2). The only difference is that (1) isn't a multi-dimensional array while (2) is. It is also worth noting that when I copy and paste (1) and (2) independently as text values myself into blank cells and put a leading equal sign, they pull the correct value. However, (2) does not get evaluated properly with either Makeformula function you provided even though it can be evaluated as pure text inserted into a new cell after the Sumproduct formula is generated. (2) leads to a #Value! error as is.

Below is how they are inputted into the cell with MakeFormula function. I used "Month End Input Frontend" for the second argument in your function because that is what the sumproduct ultimately references if run independently as seen in (1a) and (2a). Changing the 2nd argument of your first solution to "Month End Backend" doesn't work as well.

(1) =MakeFormula2(**("SUMPRODUCT(("&VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP('Inc Stmnt ''20 vs ''19'!$C11,'Month End Input Backend'!$B$4:$D$78,3,FALSE),'Month End Input Backend'!$H$4:$K$27,3,FALSE)&"="&CHAR(34)&U$7&CHAR(34)&")*("&LEFT(myvlookup($C11,'Month End Input Backend'!$B$4:$E$78,2,INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP('Inc Stmnt ''20 vs ''19'!$C11,'Month End Input Backend'!$B$4:$D$78,3,FALSE),'Month End Input Backend'!$H$4:$K$27,4,FALSE))),LEN(myvlookup($C11,'Month End Input Backend'!$B$4:$E$78,2,INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP('Inc Stmnt ''20 vs ''19'!$C11,'Month End Input Backend'!$B$4:$D$78,3,FALSE),'Month End Input Backend'!$H$4:$K$27,4,FALSE))))-1)&")*("&VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP('Inc Stmnt ''20 vs ''19'!$C11,'Month End Input Backend'!$B$4:$D$78,3,FALSE),'Month End Input Backend'!$H$4:$K$27,2,FALSE)&"))")**,"Month End Input Frontend")

^This one works

(2) =MakeFormula2(**("=SUMPRODUCT(("&VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP('Inc Stmnt ''20 vs ''19'!$C35,'Month End Input Backend'!$B$4:$D$78,3,FALSE),'Month End Input Backend'!$H$4:$K$27,3,FALSE)&"="&CHAR(34)&U$7&CHAR(34)&")*("&LEFT(myvlookup($C35,'Month End Input Backend'!$B$4:$E$78,2,INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP('Inc Stmnt ''20 vs ''19'!$C35,'Month End Input Backend'!$B$4:$D$78,3,FALSE),'Month End Input Backend'!$H$4:$K$27,4,FALSE))),LEN(myvlookup($C35,'Month End Input Backend'!$B$4:$E$78,2,INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP('Inc Stmnt ''20 vs ''19'!$C35,'Month End Input Backend'!$B$4:$D$78,3,FALSE),'Month End Input Backend'!$H$4:$K$27,4,FALSE))))-1)&")*("&VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP('Inc Stmnt ''20 vs ''19'!$C35,'Month End Input Backend'!$B$4:$D$78,3,FALSE),'Month End Input Backend'!$H$4:$K$27,2,FALSE)&"))")**,"Month End Input Frontend")

^^ This one doesn't.

Below is the outcomes of the sumproduct portions of the formulas that can pull the values correctly in both cases if copy and pasted as text values into new cells.

```
(1a) SUMPRODUCT(('Month End Input Frontend'!$C$12:$Q$12="Jan 2020")*(('Month End Input Frontend'!B13:B89="                                Sales of Product Income"))*('Month End Input Frontend'!$C$13:$Q$89))

(2a) SUMPRODUCT(('Month End Input Frontend'!$C$12:$Q$12="Jan 2020")*(('Month End Input Frontend'!B13:B89="                        Billing Fee Expense")+('Month End Input Frontend'!B13:B89="                                Medical Billing and Collection"))*('Month End Input Frontend'!$C$13:$Q$89))
```

Comment: You need to use `Worksheet.Evaluate`, so you'll need to pass the function a reference to the worksheet in some fashion. `Evaluate` is equivalent to `Application.Evaluate`, which operates in the context of the activesheet.

Comment: @BigBen I am a novice with VBA. What do you mean by passing the function a reference to the worksheet? If the sheet was called "Sheet 2", with the main sheet being "sheet 1", what would that look like?

Comment: It would help of you add an example of the `Ref` string and some sample data

Comment: @BigBen I updated the question to show you what happened when I used your answer. If anything is unclear, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`Evaluate` (or `Application.Evaluate`) operates in the context of the active sheet. You want to use `Worksheet.Evaluate`, so you need to pass the function a reference to the `Worksheet` in question. Your options include:

- Pass the sheet name as a `String`:

```
Public Function MakeFormula(ByVal Ref As String, ByVal SheetName As String) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Makeformula = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

- Pass a `Range` reference and use `Range.Parent`. Your formula would look like `=MakeFormula("yourlongformula", 'Sheet 2'!A1)`

```
Public Function MakeFormula(ByVal Ref As String, ByVal Cell As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Makeformula = Cell.Parent.Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

Comment: Another option would be to use `ThisCell` or `Caller` to identify the range containing the UDF, then get its Parent Worksheet

Comment: @chrisneilsen - I don't think so, because it sounds like it's a different sheet than the one the UDF is called from.

Comment: Hmm, you may be correct.   But the "3d" is intriguing